# Issue http://apache.org/xml/features/xinclude testing log4j 2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm testing Log4j2 and I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I downloaded the library from Apache and put them in the classpath. I added the xercesImpl, xalan, xml-apis, serializer, xsltc too and the exception still persist. I show the stack trace and the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">C:/Logs/</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/myexample.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/myexample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>


ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing C:\W7des\cliente\Test\bin\log4j2.xml javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/xinclude' is not recognized.
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.newDocumentBuilder(XmlConfiguration.java:85)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:44)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:472)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:442)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:419)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:207)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:160)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:492)
    at pac.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:14)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, removing an outdated `xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar` from the classpath helped.

Comment: Confirm - worked for me too, replaced the related dependency with xercesImpl version **2.11.0** and error is gone. Thanks!

Comment: or add `-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
` to jvm arguments

Comment: When I add the -D suggestion to my gradlew build clean -D........... It makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle JVM comes with an XML parser that supports XInclude.
According the this doc http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/sdkguide.zos.pdf the IBM J9 VM also bundles an XML parser that supports XInclude (see page 21 XML4J 4.5).

I am not sure if it is necessary to use a separate XML parser (you mentioned you are using Xerces instead of the XML parser bundled with the JVM).
What version of Xerces/Xalan are you using? What happens if you remove the custom XML parsers from the classpath?

By the way, Log4j will output WARN-level StatusLogger messages if it cannot enable XInclude.
Are you getting any WARN-level StatusLogger messages that start with "The DocumentBuilderFactory..."? Please include these messages in your question.

Unfortunately there is currently no switch in Log4j to prevent it from trying to enable the XInclude function. I suspect the problem above is a configuration issue but if it cannot be resolved you can request that such a switch be added as a new Log4j feature. The place for this is the Log4j [Jira issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2).

Comment: First of all I tested without any additional libraries and the error was the same. Then, I took the last version of Xerces (2.11) and Xalan (2.7.1). Although I remove them the problem still persist. The unique messages I see in the console are: `ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing C:\W7des\cliente\Test\bin\log4j2.xml javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/xinclude' is not recognized.
ERROR StatusLogger No logging configuration`
But the exception is about DocumentBuilderFactory...

Comment: The reason I asked about the warnings is that Log4j will output a WARN message if `DocumentBuilderFactory.setXIncludeAware(true)` fails for some reason... see also: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/xml/XmlConfiguration.html#L93

Comment: I set the property 'true' but I did not get any new messages... Here is where I think is the problem at `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)`. What could I do more?

Comment: I just resolve the problem. I have some projects added to my actual project and they have some libraries that are making my application crush with the new log4j2. I suppose that I have to select the libraries again to have not inconsistency. Thanks for all.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Configuration issues sometimes can be a real hairball to resolve...

Comment: Has anyone solved this by using Markus Schneider suggestion of passing -Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl to the Gradle build on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me after removing xerces directory from gradle caches.

```
cd ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1
rm -rf xerces
```