# Log4j2 migration - javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/xinclude' is not recognized

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

**With log4j.properties, the app is working all good. It is logging as expected. But with XML configuration it is not working**

Getting this error. I have tried all the answers from the following stackoverflow answers - [Issue http://apache.org/xml/features/xinclude testing log4j 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860361/issue-http-apache-org-xml-features-xinclude-testing-log4j-2). But no success

Following are the libraries i am using--

- log4j-1.2-api-2.15.0.jar
- log4j-api-2.15.0.jar
- log4j-core-2.15.0.jar
- log4j-jcl-2.15.0.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
- jaxen-1.2.0.jar

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 | ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing /opt/apps/user/app-name/conf/log4j.xml
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |  javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/xinclude' is not recognized.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.newDocumentBuilder(XmlConfiguration.java:191)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:89)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:46)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:524)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:499)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:422)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:322)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:695)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.getContext(LogAdapter.java:40)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/12/19 10:29:27 |       at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
```

### XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" filename="../logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="../logs/app.log.%d{yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}"
                  bufferedIO="true" bufferSize="5000000" immediateFlush="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] [%X{PID}] %c - %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="7200000" /> <!-- 2 hours -->
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 GB"/> <!-- 1 GB -->
      </Policies>
      <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="/opt/apps/user/app/logs">
          <IfFileName glob="app.log.*" />
          <IfLastModified age="7d" />
        </Delete>
      </DirectWriteRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
    <Async name="Async" bufferSize="2048">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Async>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <!-- Only log warnings for Some test package -->
    <Logger name="com.test" level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="Async"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="Async"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML configuration file here?

Comment: What JDK version are you using? The functionality described is available since [this commit](https://github.com/apache/xerces2-j/commit/f31e8d43486d87e58f02e2b49c1dd7905e998ed7) and Xerces 2.7.1. Is it possible that some other version of the library exists in your classpath or JDK?

Comment: @YogevLevy xml file is added to actual question

Comment: @jccampanero I'm using java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.6.30 - pxa6480sr6fp30-20210507_01(SR6 FP30))

Comment: Couldn't find any specific issue in the XML. Did you try some plain "example" xml, just to make sure the problem is not in the content of the xml?